# Redirect of domain to Amazon EC2 without Route53

Tags: apache, redirect, amazon-ec2

I have a website hosted in Amazon EC2.I have set my A record to point to my Elastic IP. I have also set my www to point to A record.

The problem is that both homepages exist now (the one with the domain I have in godaddy and the one with the amazon url)

I would like the ec2-.....compute.com to redirect to the homepage of my domain.

Could you help me on how to do it? Should I use somehow httpd.conf?

Comment: Why do you want anything from "ec2-.....compute.com" if you have Elastic IP?

Comment: The links in the menu of my website do not lead to the domain but to ec2-...compute.com. For instance if you click on the menu on "about" it leads to ec2-...compute.com/about and not in http://www.example.com/about

Comment: well, your links should go to example.com, not ec2-... as it may and will change!

Comment: My links and everything in my website is properly accessible and they lead to the pages within my domain. The problem is that the homepage exists for both my domain and ec2-...compute.com and SEs could recognize it as duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you would do it with httpd.conf.

But this is the alternative to make your redirection to your instance

1. Attach an Elastic IP to your instance, go to your domain management tools [ GoDaddy or Network Solutions ] and set that in your A record. **[ Recommended ]**
2. Take the public DNS of your instance, go to your domain management tools [ GoDaddy or Network Solutions ] and set that in your C record to www sub-domain

Comment: I have set my A record to point to my Elastic IP. I have also set my www to point to A record. The problem is that both websites exist now (the one with the domain record on godaddy and the one with the amazon url)

Comment: You have to remove one of them; the choice is yours. One suggest from my side is you have the WWW.mysite.com and if there is request to mysite.com you can setup redirection to www.mysite.com. This would mean you have only site and no requests left behind. There are several ways to do the redirection one easy way is to use http://wwwizer.com/ - simple point your A record to  (174.129.25.170)

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is bit old. Just wanted to know if anybody has found a solution to this question. I registered a domain in GoDaddy and have setup a VPC in Amazon EC2. Tried several means like pointing A record to Elastic IP address and updating CNAME record. But could not make  my domain accessible.

Comment: did you find the solution ? same thing